# How to autoplay next song without button interaction

Tags: reactjs, html5-audio

In my audio player, i load a song by default and then hit play button to play the audio. Now when i hit the next song button, it loads the next song but does not play it. I Have to again hit pause/play button to play it. Same thing with playing next song when previous song has ended. So, the player requires interaction to play the song after its loaded. How can i autoplay next (or previous) songs without having to interact with the player each time?

```
exports.songsdata = [
    {
        "title": "song1",
        "url": "https://song1.mp3"
    },
    {
        "title": "song2",
        "url": "https://song2.mp3"
    },
    {
        "title": "song3",
        "url": "https://song3.mp3"
    }
]

const [currentSong, setCurrentSong] = useState(songsdata[0]);
const playNext = () => {
    const index = songs.findIndex(x=>x.title == currentSong.title);

    if (index == songs.length-1)
    {
      setCurrentSong(songs[0]);
    }
    else
    {
      setCurrentSong(songs[index + 1]);
    }
}

<div className="AudioPlayer">
    <audio src={currentSong.url} />
</div>

<div className="controls">
    <Button className='btn_action' onClick={playNext} />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `canplay` event could be used to play the audio after it's loaded. So after this event called, you can call `audio.play()` to play the audio.

> Canplay event: The browser can play the media, but estimates that not
> enough data has been loaded to play the media up to its end without
> having to stop for further buffering of content.

There's also the `canplaythrough` event which is called after the audio is fully loaded.

For the autoplay feature, listen for the `ended` event of the audio tag and call the `playNext()` function from that.

> Ended event: Playback has stopped because the end of the media was
> reached.

### Example

```
const canplayEvent = () => {
  audio.play()
}

const endedEvent = () => {
  playNext()
}

<div className="AudioPlayer">
  <audio src={currentSong.url} onCanplay={canplayEvent} onEnded={endedEvent}/>
</div>
```

[More information](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio#events)

Comment: Playnext function will just load the next song. It does not play the song. If I add an audio.play() after play next, it interferes with the loading as it happens asynchronously.

Answer (score 0):

audio tag can add event **ended**.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio#events

add a event listener to the audio and once it is ended you can call playNext()

Answer (score 0):

canplay is a trick here.

```
const video = document.querySelector('video');

video.addEventListener('canplay', (event) => {
  console.log('Video can start, but not sure it will play through.');
});
```